# Dash Core components can't be loaded due to an AttributeError

Tags: python, plotly-dash

- Environment

OS: Windows 10
Python 3.8.2

The installed Dash components are: (pip list | grep dash):
dash                              1.16.2
dash-core-components              1.12.1
dash-html-components              1.1.1
dash-renderer                     1.8.2
dash-table                        4.10.1
jupyter-dashboards                0.7.0

- Used Python code

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")

dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
```

- Given result

Python script aborted with en error message in the console:

***AttributeError: module 'dash_core_components' has no attribute 'Graph'***

- Expected result
  Shown at plotly.com: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph

[image: Screenshot of expected result]

Comment: Have you tried `pip uninstall`ing and then reinstalling? Maybe the initial installation was corrupted somehow.

Comment: MY idea: It is probably due to some configuration of the involved modules. I downgraded dash and dcc (dash 1.16.0, dash-core-components 1.12.0. However, that did not help (the error remained). I will still uninstall all dash modules and reinstall freshly starting with dash. Are there any configuration files in dash/dcc where tolook for the components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now fixed and works as expected.

After I uninstalled all dash components and reinstalled them in this order:

1. dash-core-components
2. dash (tooks all dependencies)
   and rerun the script it works fine.

- My configuration at the end
  dash                              1.16.2
  dash-core-components              1.12.1
  dash-html-components              1.1.1
  dash-renderer                     1.8.2
  dash-table                        4.10.1